# What is the meaning of this GNUradio exam question?

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

> GNUradio Section 3 - Signal reception using the polyphasic clock synchronization algorithm.
>
> In this section, we will use an algorithm that corrects the delays in the clock that allows or synchronism between sender and receiver. In this diagram, the received signals appear on the left and on the right appears the sign after processing the algorithm.
>
> 1. Change the noise levels, frequency difference and clock difference and the directors effects.

What am I supposed to do in this question?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tutorials have been revised. Take a look at https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation and in particular "Using the Polyphase Clock Sync Block in Our Receiver".